# How to tee stderr from a trap?

Tags: bash, logging

I want to log everything going to `stderr` in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> >(tee -a file >&2)
trap '>&2 echo text; exit' INT
read
```

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will trigger the trap, but the output is lost. Surprisingly, using `exec 2>> file`, it will end up in the file, yet I need it to be displayed to the user as well.

How can I log `stderr`, including the trap output, while still displaying it to the user?

Comment: The interrupt is probably killing the `tee` subprocess before it gets a chance to capture the stderr.

Comment: @Barmar You are right! Thanks to that info answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `tee` to ignore the interrupt signal one can add an additional `trap '' INT` before it:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> >(trap '' INT; tee -a file >&2)
trap '>&2 echo text; exit' INT
read
```

**Edit:** Contained the trap in the subshell as sugested by @John1024 in the comments.

Comment: It might be sufficient to just swap the order of the `trap` and `exec`.

Comment: @Barmar That would make sense to me, but it does not work.

Comment: Try: `exec 2> >(trap '' INT; tee -a file >&2)`